# How to pass the Key ID back from child component to the parent component-FCC Drum Machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the element of array of object :

```js
{
   keycode:"X"
   id: 'Kick',
   url: ''
},
```

I have a stateful class component (App) which generates audio elements mapping the array and using the function PlayAudio.
This will generate buttons associated with audio element which are rendered in the parent component which will play sound on pressing the button.  Now, each objects has distinct sound , key and id associated to them.

I want to have a display element in the parent element to display the unique id associated to the button pressed. For that whenever a button is pressed that corresponding id is to be passed to parent component.

How to  send the `id` of the pressed key from the child component to the parent component?

Here is the full code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/stillness-ram/pen/VwQOLKY)

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to put the key id inside a state in the parent component and then pass the setId function to the child.
For example in the parent component:

`const [id, setId] = useState('initialValue')`

Then pass `setId` as a prop to the child.

If you prefer to use a class component this is how you declare:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: 'initialValue'
    };
  }

  ...

}
```

In a class component the property `setState` is used to change the state:
E.g.: `this.setState({ id: 'newValue' })`

You can find more info in the react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Can it be done with stateful class components too without using react hooks?

Comment: I added an example with class component. Does is answer your question?